# jQuery Browser gets freeze when to add mass rows into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

When I need to add up about 2000 elements by jQuery function append(), browser gets freeze, and seems everything stuck for some time long.

Is this because of jQuery it'self issue or.. any logical issue on my coding side?
What I am doing is like following:

```
for (var i=0; data.length; i++) {
  add_elem(data[i]);
}

function add_elem(data) {
  $("#wrapper").append('<div class="row" id="elem_' + data['id'] + '>' + data['htmlv'] + '</div>');
  uniform_elem($('#elem_' + data['id']));
}
```

uniform_elem() has some ui processing to make things look good.

Any good idea?

Comment: Do something like Juan has shown in their answer. Also, if `uniform_elem` uses `.css()` to style the elements, get rid of that, and make all styling via stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling add_elem in the loop, store all of the html for the elements in a single variable as you loop through the data variable and then invoke add_elem by passing in the new variable.

```js
var elements = "";

// Store all elements in the loop
for (var i=0; data.length; i++) {
  elements+= '<div class="row" id="elem_' + data['id'] + '>' + data['htmlv'] + '</div>';
}

// Invoke add_elem once and only once using the new elements var
add_elem(elements);

function add_elem(data) {
  // Append once to the DOM
  $("#wrapper").append(data);
  for (var j=0; data.length; j++) {
    uniform_elem($('#elem_' + data['id']));
  }
}
```

Comment: Just updated it to happen once the elements are appended to the DOM.

Comment: What problem are you running into after implementing the suggested solution?

Comment: well, because you still call the unifrom_elem function in mass looping without any time break, I guess the issue might be staying there... Anyway, up vote for putting all htmls at once.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with each object, you may do:

```
 for (var i=0;i< data.length; i++) {
 let u=i;
 setTimeout(()=>{
 add_elem(data[u]);
 },0);
 }
```

This pushes the calls onto the browsers qeue, wich is just executed when the main thread is free ( so no blocking)